# XPath returns nothing, works everywhere else

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Trying to parse this code with XPath: http://pastebin.com/Un9x1BRX
The page in action: http://fonix.dyndns.org:40000/soasc/

I want to get the composer name from this part:

```
          <td>
            <div class="hl3">
              <a href=
              "index.php?av=0&amp;sb=SOASC&amp;sc=Markus+Pyykk%F6+%28Mankeli%29&amp;clist=1&amp;did=">
              +</a>
            </div><a href=
            "index.php?av=0&amp;sb=SOASC&amp;sc=Markus+Pyykk%F6+%28Mankeli%29&amp;clist=1&amp;did=">Markus
            Pyykk&#246; (Mankeli)</a>
          </td>
```

So that it returns `Markus Pyykkö (Mankeli)`.

My XPath `./tr[@class = 'table1' or @class = 'table2']/td/a` works correctly in every online validator thingy, but SelectNodes() returns nothing. Is that my fault or is the Agility Pack broken??

Edit: I'm looping through the tracks like this:

```
HtmlNodeCollection songs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class = 'table1' or @class = 'table2']");

            foreach (HtmlNode song in songs)
            {
and so on
```

Comment: Where's the `<tr>` in your example?

Comment: <tr class="table1">, the first line in the Pastebin doc.

Comment: @skmf your code works and returns one `tr` from sample html

Comment: Over here, it keeps throwing a NullReferenceException. :c http://i.imgur.com/xLEqcgp.png

Answer (score 0):

You sure? The code below works on me,

```
var w = new HtmlWeb();
var d = w.Load("http://fonix.dyndns.org:40000/soasc/");
var xpath = "//tr[@class ='table1' or @class = 'table2']/td/a";
var anchors = d.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention (sorry!) that, since there are multiple tracks per page, I'm looping through them. (See above)